# To Delete single cron job using PHP

Tags: php, cron

I am using a php command to set up a cron job

```
<?php
   echo exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n* * * * *  /usr/local/bin/curl path" | crontab -');
?>
```

above command will add cronjob but i want to remove particular cronjob of given path so i have tried

```
<?php
 echo exec('echo -e "`crontab -r`\n1 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/curl path" | crontab -');
 ?>
```

but it's delete all cronjobs with email id.Is there any way to delete particular cron job?

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, `crontab -r` removes all cron jobs, to remove one cron tab something like this would probably work:

```
<?php
// php is weird sometimes
// the output is an array split on new lines
exec('crontab -l', $data);
// this is the one you are replacing
$val = '*/30 * * * * /path/to/awstats.pl -update -config=myconfig';
// find it in the array
$key = array_search($del_val, $data);
// key is false if not found
if($key !== false){
  unset($data[$key]);
}
// put the data back into the crontab
exec ('echo "'.implode("\n", $data).'" | crontab -');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and it's going to else for matched path but it's not delete any cron

Comment: Didn't realise that the result of an exec call was an array... had to change the code a couple of times

Comment: @BhumiShah I just updated it with code that I actually ran... seems to work now

Comment: Ya, I found out that the exec command returns an array, not a string as I expected it to. The code as it is right now should work fine, I have also added comments to the code to clarify what it is doing.

Comment: you have written exec('crontab -l', $data); so here $data = ?

Comment: what does $val = '*/30 * * * * /path/to/awstats.pl -update -config=myconfig'; line mean?

Comment: That is just the line that you are looking for, set it to whatever you want to remove from the crontab

Comment: @SeanJA, don´t know why your solution doesn't have point (it should), realized that with the -l you get a list of cronjobs, then remove it from that list and re-upload the rest of array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$match = 'yourpath';
exec('crontab -l 2>&1 | grep -v '.$match.' |  sort - | crontab -');
```

This lists the crontab, matches everything *except* the line you want deleted, and then pipes this match back in to create a new crontab.